# Store TotalCount in ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a more concise way of doing this?

```
const string TOTAL_COUNT_KEY = "totalCount";
private int TotalCount
{
    get
    {
        int safeInt = 0;
        if (ViewState[TOTAL_COUNT_KEY] != null)
            safeInt = (int)ViewState[TOTAL_COUNT_KEY];
        return safeInt;
    }
    set { ViewState[TOTAL_COUNT_KEY] = value; }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this property reside in the view model?

Comment: It's part of a paging label like "page a - b of c (x Total)" So if a user tries to filter a list she would get this label. TotalCount is total number of rows in database table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `?` operator :

```
const string TOTAL_COUNT_KEY = "totalCount";
private int TotalCount
{
    get
    {
        return ViewState[TOTAL_COUNT_KEY] != null ? (int)ViewState[TOTAL_COUNT_KEY] : 0;
    }
    set { ViewState[TOTAL_COUNT_KEY] = value; }
}
```

You can use the null propagation operator `?.`

```
const string TOTAL_COUNT_KEY = "totalCount";
private int TotalCount
{
    get
    {
        return ((int?)ViewState[TOTAL_COUNT_KEY])?.Value ?? 0;
    }
    set { ViewState[TOTAL_COUNT_KEY] = value; }
}
```

It works this way:

- We cast the `ViewState[TOTAL_COUNT_KEY]` to `int?`,
- This way, it is either null or the value (let's say `42`).
- Then, the `?.` operator will return null if the viewstate property is null, otherwise it'll return the value, 42.
- If it is null, the `??` operator will return `0`.

I think the `?` operator is the clearest, the second one is a little more ninja and might not be appropriate if some member of your team (if you have one) don't fully understand the operators.